# .EOF VB, VBA for End Of File

Tags: vba, ado

Pertaining to VBA:

Does the following mean if a record does not exist:

```
    strSQL = "Select * from tblRes  where ID = '" & Forms!Pg!PID & "'"
    rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    If rs.EOF Then
```

Does `rs.EOF` mean that the select result did not return anything?

Comment: What did the documentation tell you? No research effort evident here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with ADO recordsets like this one then yes

```
If rs.EOF
```

Will confirm there are no records, however it's worth adding that if you are working with DAO recordsets instead then you would amend to

```
If rs.BOF And rs.EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. EOF represents an "End Of File" condition.